# sorting objects by date in Mongoose not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

Trying to sort a bunch of objects by date property as follows:

```
jobInfoModel.find().sort({'someJob.created_at':1})
```

the objects come back not sorted at all regardless of whether I choose ascending or descending, but if I sort some other property it works!
my objects look like this:

```
someJob: {created_at: "Fri Nov 09 09:23:05 UTC 2018"}
```

what could be the problem here?

Comment: The date being sorted needs to be as `date` object. In case it is of _string_ data type it needs in a format like this (an example): "2020-07-26".

Answer (score 0):

as the user "parsad_" noted above, the problem was in the `created_at` property, it should be a `date` object instead of string, so I went back to my objects and changed them as follows:

```
 someJob.created_at = new Date(someJob.created_at)
```